# Insert Subtotal Formula based on ID Grouping

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a code that will insert a **subtotal formula** which will sum only cells in a column that have the correct ID grouping referenced in another column (an id group is identified by its first 2 or 3 digits).

So far I am successful with what I need to achieve only if there are *consecutive ID values* in each row. The code does not function correctly when I have blank rows and I can't figure this part out.

Any advice would be greatly appreciate it! 
See below images to understand a little bit easier.

**Current results with my posted code with color visualize code groupings.**

[image: []

**Showing Blank Rows in A and I want to subtotal by code even when blank rows appear.**
[image: []

**Formula Added By Code**

[image: []

```
Sub insertSubtotalByID()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim activeRow As Long
Dim uniqueID2 As Long
Dim uniqueID3 As Long
Dim prevuniqueID2 As Long
Dim prevuniqueID3 As Long
Dim subRow As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lastRow = Sheets("sheet5").Cells(Sheets("sheet5").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim divStartID As Long

subRow = 1
divStart = 1

uniqueID2 = Left(Cells(1, 1).Value, 2)
uniqueID3 = Left(Cells(1, 1).Value, 3)
prevuniqueID2 = Left(Cells(1, 1).Value, 2)
prevuniqueID3 = Left(Cells(1, 1).Value, 3)

For i = 1 To lastRow
     If uniqueID2 > 0 Then
        If uniqueID2 > prevuniqueID2 Then 'if current ID is greater than previous ID value
            Cells(i - 1, 3).Formula = "=SUM(INDEX($B:$B,ROW()):" & "B" & divStart & ")"
            prevuniqueID2 = Left(Cells(i, 1).Value, 2)
            divStart = i
            i = i - 1
        Else
            If i < lastRow Then

                uniqueID2 = Left(Cells(i + 1, 1).Value, 2) 'set next ID in next row, 2 values
                uniqueID3 = Left(Cells(i + 1, 1).Value, 3) 'set next ID in next row, 3 values
                prevuniqueID2 = Left(Cells(i, 1).Value, 2) 'set current ID, 2 values
                prevuniqueID3 = Left(Cells(i, 1).Value, 3) 'set current ID, 3 values

            End If
        End If

    End If

    If i = lastRow Then Cells(lastRow, 3).Formula = "=SUM(INDEX($B:$B,ROW()):" & "B" & divStart & ")"

    Cells(i, 10).Value = uniqueID2

Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Posted a solution to your empty cells issue when calculating subtotals; feel free to accept by ticking the green checkmark if you found my approach helpful. - Btw be strict in fully qualifying *any* range reference, as e.g. `cells(...)` alone would refer to any active worksheet which needn't be the one you are targeting :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Modified approach using array loop**

As looping through cells via VBA can be time consuming, I chose an array approach with the following steps:

- `[0]` get data by assigning them to a variant 1-based 2-dim datafield array `v`,
- `[1]` analyze data by comparing neighbour ids one by one via `If nxtId > curId Then`.

If this comparison reveels as true, there will follow a new ID the next row (`i+1`) and you'll have to sum at the current position `i`
       entering the sum formula (overwriting the current element):

```
   v(i, 1) = "=SUM($B$" & start & ":INDEX($B:$B,ROW()))"
```

*Note that I reverted the range address in the formula for better readibility thus starting by the top cell instead by a following row(), even if Excel can handle this*

- `[2]` The formulae are written to the target column all at once via
  `.Range("C1").Resize(UBound(v), 1).Formula2 = v`

**The issue**

> *"The code does not function correctly when I have blank rows and I cant figure this part out."*

The trick is to forget redefining the current id value if the current cell value is *empty* and to remember the prior id definition instead.

The current and next id values are provided by the help procedure `GetIDs` listed below the example call.

**Example call `InsertSubTotals`**

```
Option Explicit                           ' declaration head of code module

Sub InsertSubtotals()
With Sheet5
    '[0] get data (by assigning them to a variant 1-based 2-dim array v)
    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim v: v = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow)

    '[1] analyze data
    Dim start As Long: start = 1
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(v) - 1          ' loop from 1st element to 2nd last element
        '[1a] get current and next ids
        Dim curId As Long, nxtId As Long
        GetIDs v, i, curId, nxtId       ' call help procedure listed below

        '[1b] calculate subtotal formulae
        v(i, 1) = ""
        If nxtId > curId Then           ' compare Ids
            v(i, 1) = "=SUM($B$" & start & ":INDEX($B:$B,ROW()))"
            start = i + 1               ' remember next ID start
        End If
    Next i

    '[1c] calculate last element's formula
    v(UBound(v), 1) = "=SUM($B$" & start & ":INDEX($B:$B,ROW()))"

    '[2 ] write formulae to target column
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    .Range("C:C") = vbNullString                    ' clear target
    .Range("C1").Resize(UBound(v), 1).Formula2 = v  ' write all formulae to sheet

End With
End Sub
```

**Help procedure `GetIDs`**

The help procedure returns the neighbour id values needed for numeric comparison.

*Method:* By executing a truncation via `\ 1000` the cell value of e.g. `096700` results in 96, `102600` in 102. This is the base for the eventual comparison in step `[1b]` in the main procedure where a greater next value than the current one means the logical need to sum up.

```
Sub GetIDs(v, ByVal i As Long, curId, nxtId)
'Purpose: calculate and change current and next id values (but omitting empty cells for curId) 
'Hint:    Note that the help procedure changes the last 2 arguments as they are passed by reference
        '[2a] get current and next ids as Long Integer
        If Trim(v(i, 1)) <> vbNullString Then
           curId = v(i, 1) \ 1000      ' reset current ID only if ID <> ""
        End If
        nxtId = v(i + 1, 1) \ 1000     ' get next ID
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @T.M. You have no idea how much I appreciate this! 

So I tried testing this code out and it looks like the GetIDs sub is coming up with an error. Specifically the error lies with the "trim" function. 

"If trim(v(i, 1)) <> vbNullString Then" resulting in "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

I have not ventured into arrays yet so this is all foreign to me. Thanks again for your help so far.

Comment: Working fine for me.  - Does it raise the error already at the first element row? In any case I'd try to enter a `Debug.Print "i=" & i, v(i,1)` after the procedure call of `GetIds` in order to localize the last valid row number and element written to the VB Editor's Immediate Window. Then try to identify the next element `v(i+1)` as it can't be processed and you could analyze its vartype - @BaoN.

Comment: Did you pass all needed and correctly declared arguments? - see [Error 450 Wrong number of arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/wrong-number-of-arguments-error-450)

Comment: Hi @T.M that is correct it raises the error in the first row. I checked the Debug.Print info in the Immediate window and the values are correct. (for both i and i+1). I literally copied your code and input into the module so I believe I have all the correct declared arguments. (v,i,curID,nxtID). Do all the variables in GetIDs arguments need to be declared again? I noticed you did it for i "ByVal i As Long"

Comment: Are you actually calling: `Sub GetIDs(v, ByVal i As Long, curId, nxtId)` in section `[1]` as the error mentions a '"wrong number of arguments"*? - In response to your question: You *may* add the `Long` type to the last 2 arguments if you want (without the `ByVal`-prefix they are passed `ByRef` btw in order to return changes): `Sub GetIDs(v, ByVal i As Long, curId As Long, nxtId As Long)`. Furthermore you could try to insert a `Stop` into the `GetIds` procedure's first code line and test the following steps via `F8`. - @BaoN.

Comment: The sub is called out in this line correct "GetIDs v, i, curId, nxtId" in section [1a]? Thats what I currently have. I did the test with F8 and still get the same error. 
The code stops at the if statement with "trim" highlighted in "If trim(v(i, 1)) <> vbNullString Then" 
Afterwards it highlights in yellow the Sub heading "Sub GetIDs(v, ByVal i As Long, curId, nxtId)" with the error wrong number of arguments.

Comment: Maybe `Trim()` is stricter in your version than mine requiring a pure string argument, so try `If Trim(v(i,1) & "")) <> vbNullString Then` or replace `vbNullString` by double quotes @BaoN. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your patience in helping me even further! Im going to ask for your troubleshoot in (2) parts. 1st You are correct that the issue here lies with the Trim() function if I remove trim, the code does move forward... however I am not sure how to utilize the trim function correctly with my version. I tried your suggestions above and still get the same error. Does the trim function only work if there are actual leading or trailing spaces to work? @T.M.

Comment: 2nd. Say in an ideal spreadsheet my number coding in column A will never have spaces... (no trim function needed) if I run through the rest of the code... I get an error message in the last line of section [2] "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" Code stops here and does not input the formulas that are stored in array "v", column C is still blank essentially.

Comment: Use `.Formula` instead of `Formula2` I'm using in vers. MS Excel 365 :-) @BaoN.

Comment: Thank you! Okay! Looks like it spits out the subtotals but its not coming out correctly :( https://i.imgur.com/PG8H4sS.jpg Sorry for dragging this out so far... I feel like i'm so close to being able to use this! Also I am using Excel 2019 MSO. @T.M.

Comment: Looking at your code it seems like it would store & add a subtotal in Col C anytime the the nextID is greater than the currentID which is incorrect. It should only add a subtotal once for each grouping of codes (051000, 055000, 056000) ,(062000),(081000,088000) etc...For example for grouping (051000, 055000, 056000) it would have to check all truncated values and see that 56 is the highest and input the subtotal formula here to sum up to the lowest value in the grouping 51. Hope this makes sense..

Comment: As you want to get groups of `05....`, `06....`, `08....` etc. (and not `051...`,`055...`,`056...`), the solution is as simple as that: just change both values in `GetIds` from `1000` to `10000`, i.e. `curId = v(i, 1) \ 10000` and `nxtId = v(i + 1, 1) \ 10000`. - If that reveels helpful feel free to accept by ticking the green checkmark :-) @BaoN.

Comment: You are incredible! I finally got it to work to how I need it! Thank you so much. I really appreciate it! @T.M. I may be modifying the code a bit in the future to add other features and I may poke your brain a bit if you dont mind.. :)